# How to draw a use case diagram when an actor can change the other actor's use cases?

Tags: uml, use-case, use-case-diagram

Let's take a social group system as example;

- **Actors** are the Admin and the Moderator.
- **Use Cases :**
  ‏‏‎ ‏‏‎ ‏‏‎ ‏‏‎ ‏‏‎ ‏‏‎ ‏‏‎ ‏‏‎ ‏‏‎ ‏‏‎ ‏‏‎ ‏‏‎ ‏‏‎ ‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎ ‏‏‎ ‏‏‎ ‏‏‎  ‏‏‎ ‏‏‎ ‏‏‎ (Delete posts)
  ‏‏‎ ‏‏‎ ‏‏‎ ‏‏‎ ‏‏‎ ‏‏‎ ‏‏‎ ‏‏‎ ‏‏‎ ‏‏‎ ‏‏‎ ‏‏‎ ‏‏‎ ‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎ ‏‏‎ ‏‏‎ ‏‏‎  ‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ /
  ‏‏‎ ‏‏‎ ‏‏‎ ‏‏‎ ‏‏‎ moderator --- (Report Post)

  ‏‏‎ ‏‏‎ ‏‏‎ ‏‏‎ ‏‏‎ ‏‏‎ ‏‏‎ ‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‏‏‎  ‏‏‎ ‏‏‎ ‏⬆️
  ‏‏‎ ‏‏‎ ‏‏‎ ‏‏‎ ‏‏‎ ‏‏‎ Admin --- (Manage roles)
- Moderator's posts can be changed by admin, for example the admin can disable report posts for some moderators.

***The question is*** : How to simulate the use case diagram for this situation ?

Comment: What do you mean by "simulate the UC dia"?

Comment: Draw the use case diagram

Comment: Well, your unicode-art IS the UC diagram.

Comment: Your question title is nonsense. No actor can change another actor's use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing special to do, in a lot of cases the execution of an UC has impact on the system ... and this is the goal of these UCs.

So nothing special in the diagram, but in the textual description you can say the report was written by the moderator etc

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer, what if the admin have other case "roles" that can add or delete moderator cases

Comment: ex. admin deletes "PostReport" from moderator's use cases

Comment: @AbderrahmanElfannir if the admin can do all a moderator can do, then admin can inherit moderator. After I *only* put the UC you speak about, I never said I put all

Comment: _admin deletes "PostReport" from moderator's use cases_ that sentence has no meaning for me, what means _from moderator's use cases_ ?

Answer (score 0):

The fact that one [actor](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/use-case-actor.html) can change another user's role (and thus make the user belong to another category of actors) is without any impact on the [use case diagram](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/use-case-diagrams.html).

Why ?  Because a use case actor is a [*classifier*](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/classifier.html).  So, it does not represent the occurence of a user (i.e. a concrete user who's role might change) but a class of users having the given role.

[image]

Also important to know, a use case does not represent a workflow.  A use case represents goals that a user could have.  The [`include`](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/use-case-include.html) and [`extend`](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/use-case-extend.html) relations represent a **relation between goals and not between actions** of one and the same user. So if a user belongs to another actor class, he/she just have different goals and the old goals are no longer relevant.

If you mean to represent [workflows](https://www.batimes.com/articles/workflow-modeling-with-uml-activity-diagrams.html), you should consider using [activity diagrams](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/activity-diagrams.html) (or non-UML [BPMN diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_Process_Model_and_Notation)).  In these diagrams, you then need to foresee the course of action if the change of user role might influence the workflow.